# changing site after post request. no error message but screen page does not change

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been working with Flask, HTML and javascript. I have to re-create a pizza site for school. almost everything is going fine, I know how to go to other pages through html and python. But at some point I will be using a button which runs a javascript script which is fine. But when I try to change sites by redirecting it through flask or through html with the line (example): `

```
<li><a href={{ url_for('store') }}>Menu</a></li>
```

`

It doesn't work. I also tried redirecting it to the supposed next site since I do setup a site where it receives a json package and all of that works fine. But the only line that isn't working is the redirect line. I got get the message: "GET /payment HTTP/1.1" 200

Now I understood that if I got the message then it means all went fine. However what I wanted to happen didn't happen. So my lack of knowledge and wrong way of thinking blocks me.

I hope I can get answers here. Again, any other way of going to other sites is going well until I want to change sites with the button that uses javascript

Javascript file
`

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }

    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}

function purchaseClicked() {
    alert('Thank you for your purchase')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
        cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
    }
    
    updateCartTotal()
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
}
```

`

HTML file
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mario and Luigi's | Menu</title>
        <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/italiana" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
        <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
        
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='JS/store.js') }}" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-nav nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href={{ url_for('homepage') }}>Home page</a></li>
                    <li><a href={{ url_for('store') }}>Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href={{ url_for('about') }}>About us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="Restaurant-name Restaurant-name-large">Mario and Luigi's</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Popular Pizzas</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Margherita</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaMagherita }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$12.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Pepperoni</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaPepperoni }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$14.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button"type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Prosciutto E Funghi</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaProsciutto }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$15.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Quattro Stagioni</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaQuattros }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$17.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Hot Deals</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Star Carlos</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaStarCarlos }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$13.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Nino Bellisimo</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ PizzaNinoBel }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$15.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Marinara </span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaMarinara }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$10.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">Luigi's Specials</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Luigi's Burger Pizza</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaBurger }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$19.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-item">
                    <span class="shop-item-title">Luigi's Exotic Pizza</span>
                    <img class="shop-item-image" src="{{ pizzaExotic }}">
                    <div class="shop-item-details">
                        <span class="shop-item-price">$6.99</span>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
            
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
               
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
            </div>
            <div class="cart-total">
                <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button" onclick='myFunction();' >PURCHASE</button>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <header class="main-header">
                <nav class="main-nav nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href={{ url_for('homepage') }}>Home page</a></li>
                        <li><a href={{ url_for('store') }}>Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href={{ url_for('about') }}>About us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <h1 class="Restaurant-name Restaurant-name-large">Mario and Luigi's</h1>
                
            </header>
        </footer>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                const price = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText;
                console.log(price)
                const dict_values = {price}

                const s = JSON.stringify(dict_values);

                console.log(s)
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/test",
                    type:"POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(s)});
                }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

`

python file with flask
`

```
import json
from operator import truth
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, request, render_template, template_rendered, session, url_for
from datetime import timedelta
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "fresku"
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(hours=1)

images_folder = os.path.join('static', 'Images')

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = images_folder

price = 0

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def homepage():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session.permanent = truth
        user = request.form["nm"]
        session["user"] = user
        return redirect (url_for("store"))
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect (url_for("store"))
        return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop("user", None)
    return redirect(url_for("homepage"))

@app.route("/store", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def store():

    MagheritaPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'MargheritaPizza.jpg')
    BurgerPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'BurgerPizza.jpg')
    ExoticPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'ExoticPizza.jpg')
    MarinaraPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'MarinaraPizza.jpg')
    NinoBelPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'NinoBelPizza.jpg')
    PepperoniPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'PepperoniPizza.jpg')
    ProsciuttoPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'ProsciuttoPizza.jpg')
    QuattrosPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'QuattrosPizza.jpg')
    StarCarlosPizzaPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'StarCarlosPizza.jpg')

    return render_template("store.html",
    pizzaMagherita = MagheritaPizzaPic,
    pizzaBurger = BurgerPizzaPic,
    pizzaExotic = ExoticPizzaPic,
    pizzaMarinara = MarinaraPizzaPic,
    PizzaNinoBel = NinoBelPizzaPic,
    pizzaPepperoni = PepperoniPizzaPic,
    pizzaProsciutto = ProsciuttoPizzaPic,
    pizzaQuattros = QuattrosPizzaPic,
    pizzaStarCarlos = StarCarlosPizzaPic)

@app.route("/about")
def about():

    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route("/test", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test():
    global price

    output = request.get_json()
    result = json.loads(output)
    #this is a dict type
    print(result['price'])

    price = result['price']
    return redirect (url_for("payment"))

@app.route("/customize")
def customize():

    logoPic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'logo.jpg')
    
    return render_template("custom_page.html",
    logo = logoPic)

@app.route("/payment", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def payment():
    global price

    return render_template("pay_page.html",
    customerPay = price)

@app.route("/track_order")
def tracker():

    return render_template("tracker_page.html")
```

`

I tried redirecting it through the server with the line `

```
return redirect (url_for("payment"))
```

And tried changing the page with the line inside html

```
<li><a href={{ url_for('store') }}>Menu</a></li>
```

Link doesn't change even though it has to change. but I don't get a error message as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enclose your href URL in quotes like this:

```html
<li><a href="{{ url_for('store') }}">Menu</a></li>
```